# How to add Text to new Progrss bar in android programmatically

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-progressbar

Hi I am trying to show a new progress bar on my android app since the progress dialog is deprecated i want to use new progress bar. Right now my code does bring up progress bar but i want to add a text to it. 
See my code below

```
    RelativeLayout layout= view.findViewById(R.id.upload_layout);
    pDialog =new ProgressBar(container.getContext(),null,android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall);
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(240,255,255,255));
    pDialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    layout.addView(pDialog,params);
```

Edit:

Sorry I guess the question wasn't clear please see the image. I have no errors.

[Progress bar on the screen to which i want add text like "Uploading..."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gaLA.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: It's unclear what problem you're trying to solve here. To enable others to help you, describe the exact behavior you expected, as well as how that behavior differs from what is happening with your current implementation. Include the exact text of any error messages (including, for any exceptions, the full [stack trace](//stackoverflow.com/a/23353174) and which line of code is producing it). Please see [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You will need a separate TextView for that, add it in the RelativeLayout...
Why don't you build this progress bar in xml, and just show and hide it programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to add text "Uploading..." below the pDialog，you can add code in your code's end

```
TextView up = new TextView(pDialog.getContext());
up.setText("Uploading...");
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramUp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
paramUp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
layout.addView(up,paramUp);
```

but I suggest you build progress bar in xml.

Comment: and set pDialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);